# I am a US Citizen born in the US. I am american. I am traveling to Philippines

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, us-citizens, philippines

I want to know if I travel to the Philippines and I have a layover in Seoul Korea,  do I need a visa to transit through to my next flight to philippines?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Note that your citizenship or how you obtained it is a separate matter from how you *demonstrate* your nationality to officials when traveling, ordinarily done with a passport. You may be a U.S. citizen, but will only be treated as such if you present a U.S. passport or equivalent for identification.

Answer (score 1):

With a US passport, you don't need a visa to visit the Philippines for up to 30 days.

As you'll only be in transit in South Korea, their requirements aren't relevant (though you would be able to enter for up to 90 days)